# Struts normal JSP multiple form

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have 2 JSP pages: page1.jsp and page2.jsp and 2 action classes testAction1.java and testAction2.java. By default I am displaying the page1.jsp through the testAction1.java. Both pages have the link to go the other page. I want to know how it is possible to display the separate JSP-s through different action classes?

Also one thing I want to know whether the JSP pages can have multiple form tag where I can put different action?

Please help.

Comment: Ans to your second question is yes.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Try to describe what exact problem do you have.

Comment: Please tell me how it is possible?

Comment: `display the separate JSP-s through different action` Do you mean different JSP should be rendered after you submit the form to different action?

Comment: @Mainak Just add different form tags with different actions in the jsp. It will work.

Comment: @Aleksandr...The thing is there is one main.jsp whichhas the side navigation and upper navigation.In the side navigation there is the hyper link of those pages.Each page should be displayed through different action class.This is all what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how it is possible to display the separate jsps through
>   different action classes?

Isn't that the very basic of what Struts framework do?

> I want to know whether the jsp pages can have multiple form tag where I
>   can put different action?

Yes you can put different form tag in a JSP. Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343954/struts2-how-to-detect-submit-button-clicked-in-multiple-submit-buttons-scenario) for reference. This uses two submit buttons in the same form, but you can have two different forms altogether.