# Trouble Using Multiple <s:submit/> in One <s:form/> in a struts 2 Application

Tags: struts2

The question is in the Title. I've tried one sepcific link http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/multiple-submit-buttons.html
But no success.

Here is my code for the struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- The core configuration file for the framework is the default (struts.xml) file
and should reside on the classpath of the webapp (generally /WEB-INF/classes). -->

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- devMode equals mode debug information and reload everything for every request -->
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />

    <package name="direstrutsIndex" extends="struts-default">
        <default-action-ref name="indexLogin"/>

        <global-results>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </global-results>

        <!-- all exceptions not caught by the application will lead to error.jsp -->
        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
        </global-exception-mappings>

        <!-- 'index' action leads to the view provided by index.jsp -->
        <action name="indexLogin">
            <result>/loginPage.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="loginAction" class="direstruts.action.LoginAction" method="login">
            <result name="success">/tretas.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/loginPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/loginPage.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="registerAction" class="direstruts.action.RegisterAction" method="register">
            <result name="success">/tretas.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/loginPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/loginPage.jsp</result>
        </action>


    </package>

</struts>
```

...My code for the actions

GenericAction

```
package direstruts.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

public class GenericAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
    protected Map<String, Object> session;

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    } 
}
```

My LoginAction:

```
package direstruts.action;

import static com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action.SUCCESS;
import direstruts.model.UserBean;

public class LoginAction extends GenericAction {

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        UserBean uB = getUserBean();
        if(uB.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("userBean.username", "Por favor Insira o Username de Utilizador");
        }
        if(uB.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("userBean.password", "Por favor Insira a Password de Utilizador");
        }
    }

    public String login() throws Exception {
        System.err.println("Login!");
        if(getUserBean().getAuthentication()) {
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        if(!session.containsKey("userBean"))
            this.setUserBean(new UserBean());
        return (UserBean) session.get("userBean");
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        session.put("userBean", userBean);
    }
}
```

My RegisterAction:

```
package direstruts.action;

import static com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action.ERROR;
import static com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action.SUCCESS;
import direstruts.model.UserBean;

public class RegisterAction extends GenericAction {

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        UserBean uB = getUserBean();
        if(uB.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("userBean.username", "Por favor Insira o Username de Utilizador");
        }
        if(uB.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("userBean.password", "Por favor Insira a Password de Utilizador");
        }
    }

    public String register() throws Exception {
        System.err.println("A registar...");
        if(getUserBean().setNewUser()) {
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        if(!session.containsKey("userBean"))
            this.setUserBean(new UserBean());
        return (UserBean) session.get("userBean");
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        session.put("userBean", userBean);
    }
}
```

My LoginPage:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> 
        <title>MeeTO</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <s:form action="loginAction" method="post" >
            <s:text name="Please fill in the form below in order to Register or Log in:" /> <br>
            <s:text name="Username:"/> <s:textfield name="userBean.username" /> <br>
            <s:text name="Password:"/> <s:password name="userBean.password" /> <br>
            <s:submit value="Login" /> <br>
            <s:submit value="Register" action="registerAction" /> <br>
        </s:form>
        <s:fielderror/>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are no execution errors. What happens is when I click Login button, it Logs in. But when I click Register it Logs in as well. Somehow, struts is calling the same method (login) with the same Action (LoginAction) in Register button and i don't know why. And i don't want to use multiple form tags.

Comment: It worked!! Sorry for not searching All previous questions. Can you post an answer so I can upvote it, or shall I upvote the one you mentioned?

Comment: I'm still a noob :/
I can't yet upvote my own finger if i wished.

Comment: You can answer yourself and accept it. And when you have enough rep upvote mentioned answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to put a constant in struts.xml file

```
    <constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
```

Like  Aleksandr M said, by indicating the the:

[How to detect submit button clicked in multiple submit buttons scenario in single Action class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343954/struts2-how-to-detect-submit-button-clicked-in-multiple-submit-buttons-scenario)

Many Thanks to you all. (My first Stack Overflow question BTW :D)

Comment: If you want to thank him, you can upvote his answer (the one that you linked)

Comment: I upvoted  Aleksandr M answer in his link and voted his comment as usefull. Is that ok?

Comment: absolutely yes ;) (voting questions and answers is important, while comments doesn't generate rep; voting them will just make them spawn among the top 5 before the *show X more comments* link)