# My action attribute on my Struts submit tab does not send me to the correct struts action

Tags: struts2

Looking at the documentation  [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/multiple-submit-buttons.html) I thought I should be able to use a submit button to go to an action different from the`action` attribute of the  `form` which contains the button.  But when I use the code below it goes to the `nameSearch` action instead of the `newRequest` action when I click on the button.  The `nameSearch` action is in a different `namespace` than the `newRequest` action.  Does that cause a problem?  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<s:form action="nameSearch" method="post" validate="false">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right"> 
        <s:submit action="newRequest" value="Cancel"  />
    </div>
</s:form>
```

**EDIT**:  The relevant xml code is

```
<package name="eval" namespace="/eval" extends="default">
   <action name="newRequest" class="gov.mo.dnr.egims.controller.evaluation.NewRequestAction">           
        <result name="success" type="tiles">newRequest</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">error</result>
   </action>

    <action name="newRequest_NameSearch" class="gov.mo.dnr.egims.controller.evaluation.NewRequestAction" method = "generateNameList">           
        <result name="success" type="tiles">newRequest</result>
        <result name="nameSearch" type="tiles">nameSearch2</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">error</result>            
    </action>
</package>

<package name="req" namespace="/req" extends="default">
    <action name="nameSearch" class="gov.mo.dnr.egims.controller.request.NameSearchAction">
         <result name="success" type="tiles">nameSearch</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">error</result>
    </action>  
</package>
```

I get to the button via the `newRequest_NameSearch` action.  I tried changing the `action` attribute of the button to `action="/eval/newRequest"` but it still went to the `nameSearch` action.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13343954/1700321 + namespace.

Comment: The problem was I didn't have `<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />` in my struts.xml which you mentioned in your answer at the other link.

Comment: If they made the action attribute disabled by default does that mean it is a security issue to turn it on?

Comment: No security issue but it could be a result future fixes. See release notes and read security bulletins to be aware about security.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information about struts.xml. I guess the framework couldn't find `newRequest` in the namespace `/`, then it falling back to `nameSearch`.

Look at the example from Struts [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/namespace-configuration.html):

```
<package name="default">
    <action name="foo" class="mypackage.simpleAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">greeting.jsp</result>
    </action>

<package name="mypackage2" namespace="/barspace">
    <action name="bar" class="mypackage.simpleAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">bar2.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

If a request is made to `/barspace/foo.action`, the namespace `/barspace` will be checked for action foo. If a local action is not found, the default namespace is checked. In the Namespace Example, there is no action `foo` in the namespace `/barspace`, therefore the default will be checked and `/foo.action` will be executed.